# How do I express projection of $z$ onto $x$ as a linear combination of $x$ and $y$?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image: This is the problem]

I have no idea how to do this problem and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to find $u,v\in W$ such that $\langle u,u\rangle = \langle v,v\rangle = 1$ and $\langle u,v\rangle = 0$. Then $\operatorname{proj}_W(z) = \langle z,u\rangle u + \langle z,v\rangle v$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$V=W\oplus   W^\perp $, so you can write $z=ax+by+c\alpha $ where

$ax+by=\text{ proj }_Wz\ $ and $\ x\cdot \alpha =y\cdot \alpha =0$.

Thus, from the data, we have

$z\cdot x=3=a+b+0$

$z\cdot y=1=a+5b+0$

and we find that $a=7/2;\ b=-1/2$